# How can I change this method to query my master detail object?

Tags: apex, soql, lookup, master-detail

I am new to Apex trying to do some practice assignments and have gotten stuck on this junction object query.

**Task:** Edit the current getUser() method to do the following:

Return a custom object (that you define in the class) with the current getUser method's query data, **and** the list of teams the person belongs to (by querying the team assignments).

- Parent Object 1: User (Standard Object)
- Parent Object 2: Team (Custom Object)
- Junction Object: Team Assignments (Custom Object)
  [image]

```
**Original Class & getUser Method**
global class CTI {
    global class CTIException extends Exception {}

    global static User getUser() { 
        return [SELECT Id, Name, ProfileId, Profile.Name, UserRoleId, UserRole.Name, Username 
                FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I return a Custom Object with a List of Parent Data from querying the Junction Object?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271974/how-can-i-return-a-custom-object-with-a-list-of-parent-data-from-querying-the-ju)

Comment: I'm voting to leave this one open, as it has more content than the other version of this same question.

Answer (score 1):

> Approach 1, return a User SObject with children that identify Teams

```
public static User getUdserData() {
   return [SELECT Id, UserName, ...,
            (SELECT Team__r.Name 
               FROM Team_Relationships__r)
            FROM User
            WHERE Id = UserInfo.getUserId()];
}
```

> Approach 2 - return a custom type

```
public class UserData {
   public User u;
   public Team__c[] userTeams = new List<Team__c>();
}

public static UserData getUser() { 
    UserData ud = new UserData();
    ud.u = [SELECT Id, Name, ProfileId, Profile.Name, UserRoleId, UserRole.Name, Username 
            FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() ];
    for (Team_Assignment__c ta: 
      [SELECT Team__r.Name FROM Team_Assignment__c
         WHERE User.Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()]) {
      ud.userTeams.add(ta.Team__r.Name);
    }
    return ud;
}
```

So, a custom type is returned with the User and a list of Team__c

Comment: This did not work for me, I did edit the getUser() method to global static List<Team_Assignment__c> getUser() since the assignment said to query Team_Assigment__c and to return a custom object which Team Assignment is. But it was not defined in the class.

Comment: I have gotten my base query but now just trying to add the rest
```List<Team_Assignment__c> userTeams = [SELECT Team__r.Name FROM Team_Assignment__c WHERE User__r.Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() ];
        return userTeams;
```

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood the question/your assignment. So, are you still having an issue now and if so, use the edit link to amend your question

Comment: Edited! Hopefully that helps make it more concise. I still need help. What I currently have is,
``` 
global static List<Team_Assignment__c> getUser() {
        User currentUser = [SELECT Id, Name, ProfileId, Profile.Name, UserRoleId, UserRole.Name, Username FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() ];

        List<Team_Assignment__c> userTeams = [SELECT Team__r.Name FROM Team_Assignment__c WHERE User__r.Id = :currentUser.Id ];
        return userTeams;
    }
```

Comment: ok, round 2 - not super clear on the assignment but between this and the previous answer you should have enough

Comment: Basically my issue is I need to return the original information from the original getUser method, along with a list of Teams Names that the User belongs to within the same return object.

Comment: My first answer did that