# How can I return a Custom Object with a List of Parent Data from querying the Junction Object?

Tags: apex, soql, lookup, master-detail, junction-object

I am new to Apex trying to do some practice assignments and have gotten stuck on this junction object query.

**Task:**
Edit the current getUser() method to do the following:

- Return a custom object (that you define in the class) with the current getUser method's query data, **and** the list of teams the person belongs to (by querying the team assignments).
- Parent Object 1: User (Standard Object)
- Parent Object 2: Team (Custom Object)
- Junction Object: Team Assignments (Custom Object)

[image]

```
**Original Class & getUser Method**
global class CTI {
    global class CTIException extends Exception {}

    global static User getUser() { 
        return [SELECT Id, Name, ProfileId, Profile.Name, UserRoleId, UserRole.Name, Username 
                FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() ];
    }
}
```

I have tried adding subqueries into my main query, but the verbiage tripping me up is the custom object defined in the class to be returned.

Comment: How is this different from this question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271861/how-can-i-change-this-method-to-query-my-master-detail-object

Comment: I already flagged the previous because I could not delete it, as I wanted to rewrite it entirely.

Comment: Since the older question appears to have more content on it, I'll be closing this version as the duplicate.